# How does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^n}{n!} = e^p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^n}{n!} = e^p$? I know that it is a geometric sum but I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: It is not a geometric series: the ratio of consecutive terms is not constant, because of the factorial in the denominator.

Comment: It depends on where you start.  If you know $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x=e^x$ then you could take a [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: And in some treatments the infinite series is taken to be the *definition* of $e^p$.

Comment: Whoops sorry, thanks for pointing it out. @BrianM.Scott , the reason I asked is because I was reading my notes and it just stated the above result. So I take it, it is a 'standard' definition for $e$?

Comment: Another way: $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ satisfies: $f$ is continuous, increasing, $f(1)=e$ and $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: "So I take it, it is a 'standard' definition for e?" - it's one of the ways to define it. Which brings us to the question of what definition is being used in your notes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Richard, the sum is *not* a geometric series, since the ratio is not constant:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac p {n+1} $$ It is rather the series representation for the exponential function $y=e^x$.

We know from the theory of Taylor polynomials and series that if we have a function $f$ that is differentiable inifinitely many times, then under appropriate conditions we can define it's Taylor series around a point $x=a$ as

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

The appropriate condition is that the error produced by the $n$th approximation, which assuming the integrability of $f^{(n)}$, can be proven to be

$$E_n(a,x) = \int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt$$

will tend to zero for $n\to \infty$. The error expression which looks quite strange is not too hard to derive. I transcribe from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112958/the-error-term-in-taylor-series-and-convolution) question of mine:

> $$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+R_1(x)$$ so that
> $$R_1(x) = f(x)-f(a) - f'(a) (x-a)$$
> $${R_1}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {f'\left( t \right)dt}  - \int\limits_a^x {f'(a)dt} $$
> $${R_1}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {f'\left( t \right) - f'\left( a \right)dt} $$
> So now we integrate by parts with
> $$f'\left( t \right) - f'\left( a \right) = u$$
> $$t - x = v$$
> to get
> $${R_1}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {\left( {x - t} \right)f''\left( t \right)dt} $$
> We can similarily do this with $R_2(x)$, since
> $${R_2}(x) = {R_1}(x) - f''\left( a \right)\frac{{{{\left( {x - a} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}$$
> $${R_2}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {\left( {x - t} \right)f''\left( t \right)dt}  - \int\limits_a^x {\left( {x - t} \right)f''\left( a \right)dt} $$
> $${R_2}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {\left( {x - t} \right)\left( {f''\left( t \right) - f''\left( a \right)} \right)dt} $$
> So again integrating by parts gives
> $${R_2}(x) = \int\limits_a^x {\frac{{{{\left( {x - t} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}f'''\left( t \right)dt} $$

In the case of the exponential function, we can prove that the error indeed goes to zero, from where we can represent it around $x=a$ as

$$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^a }{n!}(x-a)^n$$

since it is the case $f^{(n)}(a) = e^a$ for the exponential function.

It is important to note some authors **define** $$\exp(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n }{n!}$$

and derive then the properties of the function (note this is the series around $x=0$).

**NOTE** The error term in $(1)$ is used whenever $f^{(n)}$ is integrable. Else, we need other formulas, such as Cauchy's or Lagrange's.

Comment: Thanks Peter, most appreciated. Really clear answer and gave me a better understanding!

Answer (score 6):

A very polished development of this series expression for the exponential function is given in the opening section of W. Rudin's [Real and Complex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Real_and_complex_analysis.html?id=Z_fuAAAAMAAJ).  Rudin's approach is to take the power series as defining a holomorphic function (since the radius of convergence is infinite) and briefly prove that the function equals its derivative.  Moreover if one specifies the value at the origin $f(0)=1$, then this characterizes the exponential function.  The usual properties of the exponential function can also be deduced from the series, e.g. $e^x e^{-x} = 1$, from which it follows that $e^x$ is never zero.