# Could you prove convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, irrational-numbers

Two questions:

Prove $a_n$  is bounded by 2 if $a_1=0, a_2=\sqrt2,\ldots,a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$

Prove (I've already proven $s_n$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above by 3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=e$ for $s_n=(1+\frac1n)^n$.

Comment: Special case of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 10):

It is true for $a_1=0$. Now suppose true for $a_n$. Then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}\leq \sqrt{2+2}=2$ so by induction this is true for every $n\geq 1$.

How are you defining $e$ for the second question? Sometimes that is just the definition! See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1/152616#152616) for example, or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139630/how-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracpnn-ep/139640#139640) for such "definition depending" problems.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter already said in his answer, your second question's answer may depend on how you define the number $\;e\;$, yet you can also check the following *function's* limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{x+1}=1$$

and from here you get what you want.